# Plot a vertical line using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to draw a vertical line with Matpotlib and I'm using `axvline`, but it doesn't work.

```
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')

from ui_courbe import *
from PyQt4 import  QtGui
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.boutonDessiner.clicked.connect(self.generatePlot)

    def generatePlot(self):
        # generate the plot 
        ax = self.graphicsView.canvas.fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot([1,3,5,7],[2,5,1,-2])
        plt.axvline(x=4)
        self.graphicsView.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can see my plot, but no vertical line. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example is not self contained, but I think you need to replace:

```
plt.axvline(x=4)
```

with:

```
ax.axvline(x=4)
```

You are adding the line to an axis that you are not displaying. Using `plt.` is the pyplot interface which you probably want to avoid for a GUI. So all your plotting has to go on an axis like `ax.`

Answer (score 5):

### [`matplotlib.pyplot.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html#matplotlib-pyplot-vlines)

- The difference is that you can pass **multiple locations** for `x` as a list, while [`matplotlib.pyplot.axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html#matplotlib-pyplot-axvline) only permits one location.

  - Single location: `x=37`
  - Multiple locations: `x=[37, 38, 39]`
- If you're plotting a figure with something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, then replace `plt.vlines` or `plt.axvline` with `ax.vlines` or `ax.axvline`, respectively.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.linspace(1, 21, 200)
plt.vlines(x=[37, 38, 39], ymin=0, ymax=len(xs), colors='purple', ls='--', lw=2, label='vline_multiple')
plt.vlines(x=40, ymin=0, ymax=len(xs), colors='green', ls=':', lw=2, label='vline_single')
plt.axvline(x=36, color='b', label='avline')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]