# Add vertical dashed line between line and x axis using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot that looks like this:
[image]

I plot those arrows using the annotate method

```
ax.annotate('sample events', (x_value, y_value), xytext=(x_value, -3000), rotation=90, va='top', arrowprops = {'width': 2, 'headwidth': 4, 'linestyle': '--'})
```

but what I want is something like:
[image]

and it's better if the annotation text is on the x-axis, is there any way to do it?

(I've tried ax.axvline(x=x_value) but it makes vertical lines across the whole plot)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot a vertical line using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096948/plot-a-vertical-line-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1):

The easy method is to use `ax.stem`, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.random.random(20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y)
ax.stem(y, markerfmt='.')
plt.show()
```

Resulting example plot is:

[image]

If You want to hide horizontal line, then use `basefmt = " "`:

```
ax.stem(y, basefmt = " ", markerfmt='.')
```

Answer (score 0):

At first: You should avoid `#` within your code, since it will then be interpreted as a [comment](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_comments.asp).

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) of `ax.annotate`, you should easily specify the line type as dashed, as well as the label placement. **A good list of examples can be found [here](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-7-matplotlib/examples/arrow-styles/https://scipython.com/book/chapter-7-matplotlib/examples/arrow-styles/).**

You should try something similar to: `ax.annotate('dashed line', xy=(0.25,0.2), xytext=(0.6,0.2),arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '-', 'ls': 'dashed'}, va='center', rotate=90)`

Comment: `annotate` is such a cumbersome method compared to `stem`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just deleted the '#' in the question