# How to add a baseline and written values next to the bars in a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to work out how to add a physical baseline at 0 in my bar chart, and how to write P values to the right of each of my bars.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

Firstandtotalorder  = {"First order indices": [0.081, -0.05, 1.11],
                       "Total order indices":[0.013, 0.047, 1.212]};

index = ["BOD1", "BOD2", "BOD3"];

dataFrame  = pd.DataFrame(data = Firstandtotalorder);

dataFrame.index = index;

dataFrame.plot.barh(rot=15, title="First and total order sobol indices", xlim = -0.2);

plot.show(block=True);
```

[Plot requiring further formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf4pI.png)

P values for First order indices = 0.01, 0.02, 0.03 (for example)
P values for Total order indices = 0.04, 0.05, 0.06 (for example)

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: For drawing a vertical line: `plt.axvline(0, color='k')`.  To add text: `plt.text(x, y, text)`.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot a vertical line using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096948/plot-a-vertical-line-using-matplotlib)

Comment: Also [Putting text in top left corner of matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482588)